# Java Desktop Application - memory

Tags: java, executable-jar

I'm creating a java desktop application(Runnable jar file). I'm getting a path from user when running it for first time (like workspace in eclipse).

I want the application to remember the path when I'm closing the application and running it again (like eclipse remembering the workspace).

But I cant do it because everytime when I close the application and running it again all variables will be reinitialized.

Eclipse is also a desktop application. How eclipse is doing it and how can I implement it in my application.

Comment: You need so save the values to a file or database or anything that lives longer than your application. Take a look at ``Properties`` since that's an easy way to load and save config files in java.

Comment: Desktop apps that need to persist state usually have a *config file*. Like the `eclipse.ini`

Comment: You may also have a look at the _Preferences_ API : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Berger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5612858/berger) you can use the `Preferences` API as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        Preferences userRoot = Preferences.userRoot();
        String workspace = userRoot.get("workspace", null);
        if (null != workspace) {
            System.out.println(workspace);
            System.out.println("Would you like to change the value (Y/N):");
            String option = in.nextLine();
            if ("Y".equals(option) || "y".equals(option)) {
                updateWorkspace(in, userRoot);
            }
        } else {
            updateWorkspace(in, userRoot);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void updateWorkspace(Scanner in, Preferences userRoot) {
    String workspace;
    System.out.println("Enter value for workspace:");
    workspace = in.nextLine();
    userRoot.put("workspace", workspace);
}
```

This is just a sample example. Based on your need you can make changes accordingly.